# How to save selected option in UIPickerView

Tags: swift, overloading, xcode8, nsuserdefaults, uipickerview

I have a PickerView which should save the selected pickerView but it is selecting only the default option.I have tried using user default but it didn't work.

I am using Xcode 8.

```
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pizzaToppings.count
        
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        pizzaTextField.text = pizzaToppings[row]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(row, forKey: "pickerViewRow")
       
    }
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attrb = NSAttributedString(string: pizzaToppings[row])
        return attrb
        
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pizzaToppings[row]
    }
```

And In overload function I have used user default

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    let row = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pickerViewRow")
    pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.set(pizzaToppings[row], forKey: "pickerViewRow") in didSelectRow

Comment: Why use both attributed title for row and title for row? And why use xcode 8?

Comment: @williamfinn I have tried changing row to pizzaToppings[row] but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what are you doing here. In `viewDidLoad()` you find the row (saved at `pickerViewRow` of `UserDefaults`) that the first time is 0. Then you select the first - default row. If you tap a row of picker view then you set the row at UserDefaults. The problem here is that inside `viewDidLoad()` your UI picker view does not have elements from your data source. You can move your code of `viewDidLoad` inside `viewDidAppear` and it should work.

Comment: Have you set the datasource of pickerView to pizzaToppings?